# Facebook APIs to retrieve deleted campaign insights

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm using the python Facebook API's SDK.
I am currently able to request and obtain campaign insights from the account level, with a snippet as such:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights as Insights
account = AdAccount(u"act_{}".format(account_id))
report_params = {
    'time_increment': time_increment,
    'time_range': {
        'since': start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'until': end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    },
    'level': 'campaign'
}
insights = account.get_insights(fields=['campaign_name', 'spend'],
                                params=report_params, pending=True).execute()
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get information about a **deleted** campaign, that was active for a time, meaning that it has a *spend* value.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/) I read that adding a filtering might give me also DELETED or ARCHIVED campaigns, but in the `get_insights` [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v5.0) I can't seem to find a field to filter on, and every try has been unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right filter, even though the `effective_status` is not obtainable through insight fields, you can use it in filters, in my case I included every possible `campaign.effective_status`. Using the following `report_params`

```
report_params = {
    'time_increment': time_increment,
    'time_range': {
        'since': start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        'until': end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    },
    'level': 'campaign',
    'filtering': [{'field': 'campaign.effective_status',
                   'operator': 'IN',
                   'value': ['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED', 'DELETED', 'PENDING_REVIEW', 'DISAPPROVED', 
                             'PREAPPROVED', 'PENDING_BILLING_INFO', 'CAMPAIGN_PAUSED', 'ARCHIVED',
                             'ADSET_PAUSED']}]
}
```